# How to get value from id to c# code behind file

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0

Javascript:

```
 document.getElementById('DisplayEmail').innerHTML = me.email;
```

HTML:

```
 Your Email : <span id="DisplayEmail" runat="server"></span>
```

I need to get the value of `displayEmail` to textbox.

Please can any one help me

Comment: What is the question here? Is there an error if so what?

Comment: it is not error document.getElementById('DisplayEmail').innerHTML = me.email; value to c# code

Comment: So you want to turn JavaScript into C# code? That doesn't make any sense?

Comment: need diaplayemail value into textbox

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
document.getElementById('DisplayEmail').innerHTML = '<%=me.email%>';
```

Comment: Compilation Error, it says me does not exist in current context

Comment: Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'me' does not exist in the current context

Source Error:

Line 57:                         document.getElementById('DisplayEmail').innerHTML = '<%=me.email%>';

Comment: This answer should do it. Just that the compiler is looking of your me.email. Please make sure it exists before injecting it on the HTML element. You can try isolating the flow by using breakpoints or displaying the value before using it.